# Multiple equations in Simulink switch on and off with certain conditions

Tags: matlab, modeling, simulink

I have a model that I input in Simulink.
The model can be found here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/684191
At the bottom of the page, The Final, non-Simplified Momentum Balance.

I set the initial time as 0.0001 as 0 forces an error.

Now my problem.  This equation is only valid as long as M2 > 0
I want that function to be stopped if that condition is no longer true.
And after that, the is another two equations that I want to run that is also only valid up to one point.

If you integrate the model equation twice, you find x(height above ground).
The other two formulas produce a value for x as well.
I then want to add all 3 of the values together to produce a path.

Comment: You need to put the parts of your model that need to be turned on and off in enabled subsystems.  For the specific case you mention here, one of the enable signals would be the condition that M2 > 0 (or not) to have that part of the model continue executing or not.

Comment: Using Enabled Subsystem block does not seem to work.  The output value cannot be used as on/off trigger here.  Simulink gives me an error?

Comment: "Direct feedback connections involving nonvirtual subsystem 'vddt/Enabled Subsystem' are not allowed".  M2 is within the subsystem.  How do activate my subsystem when the inside determines whether it is active or not? M2 does have an initial, non zero value.

Comment: You can't calculate M2, then decide if you want to calculate M2.  You can either calculate M2, then decide if you want to use it in another part of the model at this time step, or decide if you want to use it to determine if M2 should be recalculated at the next time step.  In the later case feed it out of the subsytem, into a unit delay (or memory) block, and use the delayed signal as the enable of the subsystem.

Comment: I thank you sincerely for your help Phil.  This helped alot.